# 2D Terraria-style terrain generation in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, terrain

I've been puzzling over this for a while.  Basically, I am trying to, as the title says, generate a tile-based two-dimensional terrain like in [Terraria](http://www.terraria.org/).  As of now, I'm basically just generating a bunch of random points that will eventually be the top layer of the terrain, which looks like this:

```
- (void)generatePoints
{
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    self.topTerrainPoints = [[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:terrainKeyPoints];
    for (int i = 0; i < terrainKeyPoints; i++) {
        _terrainPoints[i] = CGPointMake(x, y);
        if (i != 0) {
            int newElevation = [self getRandomElevation];
            x += 64;
            y += newElevation;
            CCLOG(@"Point added!");
        }
    }
    [self populatePointsWithBlocks];
}
```

After that, I'm populating those points with "Blocks" (Subclass of CCSprite)

```
- (void)populatePointsWithBlocks
{
    for (int i = 0; i < terrainKeyPoints; i++) {
        Block *tile = [[Block alloc] initWithType:kBlockTypeGrass];
        tile.position = ccp(_terrainPoints[i].x, _terrainPoints[i].y);
        [self addChild:tile];
        [self.topTerrainPoints addObject:tile];
        CCLOG(@"Tile added!");
    }
    [self fillInGround];
}
```

I then proceed to fill in about ten layers beneath each block:

```
- (void)fillInGround
{
    for (int j = 1; j < terrainMaxDepth; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < terrainKeyPoints; i++) {
            CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(_terrainPoints[i].x, _terrainPoints[i].y - 64 * j);
            Block *dirt = [[Block alloc] initWithType:kBlockTypeDirt];
            dirt.position = newPoint;
            [self addChild:dirt];
        }
    }
}
```

This produces decent results, but I would like to eventually have caves and other materials in the ground as well, if you know what I mean.

I have two questions:

1. Is this a wise way of generating terrain?  If not, how should I do so?
2. If this way of creating terrain is fine, how exactly would I proceed to add caves and different block types into the already generated terrain.

I hope all this makes sense, and I can post pictures or answer any questions you may have.

Anyway, Thanks!

EDIT: Anyone?

Comment: a starting point for further research: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Comment: This is interesting, I'll definitely read this over, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you'll need terrain generation? Maybe it would not be suitable for your game, but you could always create the levels before-hand, using a tool like LevelHelper. You can create different types of blocks, and code them, and then its simply just a drag-and-drop to create your levels. 
http://www.levelhelper.org/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but yes, I do want random level generation. I was hoping to create the game like Terraria or Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to that. What you will need to do is a grid, so you can have like  a Tiled Map. So you will be able to access the block 1, 4 (but it's position in pixels will be different.

To do this you should have a two dimension array. To do this in Objective C you will need to have a NSArray containing other NSArrays. The first array, will be the Y position of the second array objects. 
For example:
`[[blockArray objectAtIndex:2] objectAtIndex:5]` 
will get the block at coord (2, 5).

You then can create methods to translate grid coords to cocos2D pixel coords or viceversa.

The main reason to use this grid is that you will need to access to certain block at any time (for example translating a position in pixels to a position in our grid), instead of recourse all the Array (witch will make your game lag a lot) and checking if a block collides.

Hope it helps!